# Log-Sum-Exp as an approximation of min function

Tags: approximation, limits-without-lhopital, maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds, exponential-sum

I can prove that the function:
$$f(\tau, x_1, x_2, ..., x_N) = -\tau \log \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \exp{\left(-\frac{x_i}{\tau}\right)} $$ converges to $\min(x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)$ for $x_i \geq 0$ as $\tau \to +0$ using the L'Hospital's rule (by substitution $\tau=\frac{1}{\rho}$ and finding the limit $\rho \to +\infty$)

However, I need also to find the upper bound of the approximation error:
$$\left| f(\tau, x_1, x_2, ..., x_N) - z \right| \leq h(\tau, x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)$$
where $z=\min(x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)$.

Using Jensen's inequality and fact that $-\log(y)$ is convex I can show that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left| f(\tau, x_1, x_2, ..., x_N) - z \right| &= -\tau \log \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \exp \left( -\frac{x_i - z}{\tau} \right) \leq \\ &\leq -\frac{\tau}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \log \exp \left( -\frac{x_i - z}{\tau} \right) = \bar{x} - z,
\end{split}
\end{equation} where $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum x_i$. However, this bound doesn't depend on parameter $\tau$.

**I wonder if there any sharper upper bound, which depends on $\tau$?**

Comment: I suppose you mean "$\tau \rightarrow 0^+$", since the two-sided limit doesn't exist.  Also, I have trouble with your limit claim.  For $N = 1$, $x_1 = 1$, as $\tau \rightarrow 0^-$, $f \rightarrow \infty$ and as $\tau \rightarrow 0^+$, $f \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @EricTowers thanks for the comment, yes, I looking for a limit $\tau \to +0$. I apply L'Hospital's rule by substituting $\tau = \frac{1}{\rho}$. Then $\rho \to +\infty$

Comment: @EricTowers in that case I get: $$ -\frac{\log \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \exp ( -\rho x_i) }{\rho} $$
as $\rho \to +\infty$

Comment: @EricTowers it is $\lim_{\rho \to +\infty} -\frac{\log \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} e ^ {( -\rho x_i)} }{\rho}$, which is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may rearrange the $x_i$ so that they are sorted $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \cdots \leq x_N$.  Then 
\begin{align*}
f(\tau, x_1, \dots, x_N) &= -\tau \ln \left( \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \mathrm{e}^{-x_i/\tau} \right)  \\
&= -\tau \left( \ln\left( \frac{1}{N}\mathrm{e}^{-x_1/\tau} \right) + \ln \left( 1 + \sum_{i=2}^N \mathrm{e}^{(x_1-x_i)/\tau} \right) \right)  \\
&= -\tau \left( -\ln(N) - \frac{x_1}{\tau} + \ln \left( 1 + \sum_{i=2}^N \mathrm{e}^{(x_1-x_i)/\tau} \right) \right)  \\
&= \tau \ln(N) + x_1 - \tau \ln \left( 1 + \sum_{i=2}^N \mathrm{e}^{(x_1-x_i)/\tau} \right)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Therefore, 
$$  |f(\tau, x_1, \dots, x_N) - x_1| = \left| \tau \ln(N) - \tau \ln \left( 1 + \sum_{i=2}^N \mathrm{e}^{(x_1-x_i)/\tau} \right) \right|  \text{.}  $$
For $\tau$ sufficiently small, the sum expression in the the parentheses is $\varepsilon \ll 1$, so \begin{align*}
|f(\tau, x_1, \dots, x_N) - x_1| &= \left| \tau \ln(N) - \tau \ln \left( 1 + \varepsilon \right) \right|  \\
&= \tau \left| \ln(N) - \left(\varepsilon + O(\varepsilon^2) \right) \right|  \\
&\approx \tau \ln N  \text{.}  
\end{align*}

Visually inspecting graphs of $f$ versus $\tau$ for several choices of $N$ and $x_i$, this does capture the near zero behaviour.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In fact, is it correct to write that 
$$ | f(\tau, x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) - x_1 | = \tau | \log (N) - \log(1 + \varepsilon) | \leq \tau | \log N |,$$ since $ \varepsilon \geq 0$?

Comment: @dm_k : I believe so.  Not making that shift is a holdover from the "Therefore, [display equation].", when I wasn't sure whether the positive term or negative term would dominate (for what ranges of $\tau$).  For $N>1$, since we can take $\varepsilon \ll \min\{ 1 , \ln N \}$, that works.  For $N = 1$, $\varepsilon = 0$ and the equality in your inequality holds.

Comment: Everything is clear now. Thanks a lot for the help.